# laravel validation doesn't pass my none required fields

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have problem with my laravel valdation

the problem is :

I have two none required  fields ( password and birthday )

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email,'.Auth::id(),
            'birthday'=>'date',
            'password'=>'confirmed|min:6',

        ];
    }
```

I can't pass the birthday and the password if they are empty

the error is

```
The birthday is not a valid date.
The password must be at least 6 characters.
```

I did `dd(Input::All())` inside the rules function and both fields are empty `( null )`

any idea about this problem ? ? ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the [`nullable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-nullable) validation:

```
return [
    'name'=>'required',
    'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email,'.Auth::id(),
    'birthday'=>'nullable|date',
    'password'=>'nullable|confirmed|min:6',
];
```

This will allow your fields to be empty. But if they're not empty, they'll be constrained by the other validation rules (e.g. `date`).

Comment: its work fine thank you so much , I always do the same as what   in  my question but there was  no problem and i didnt use nullable before , why now ??